# Efficient storage of parameters in C

Tags: c, embedded

I have an application where I need to store values, those values can be either a double, an integer, a string (fixed size char array), uint8_t, chars, ...

Each of these values also has additional parameters, it can be Read-Only, Read-Write or they can have a max or min value (obviously for numeric types only).

So basically a simple struct would look like this:

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t current_val;
    uint32_t min;
    uint32_t max;
    uint8_t type;
    uint32_t initial_value;
    uint8_t access_mode = READ_WRITE;
} valueType;
```

Now obviously this struct could only hold a uint32_t parameter value. I'd like to have many of those with different types and then store them in a common array.

Do you see any chance of doing this except for storing the reference to the instance and then finding out what the parameter type actually is?

I've seen a solution where for each of those parameters a memory section was allocated and then parameter was stored there. So basically the largest parameter was a 32byte string which caused even an uint32_t to occupy 32 bytes.

What would be the correct way to address this issue? Is there some common way to do this? Maybe just throw in some term so I know what to google for.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `union`.

Comment: I've been thinking about that as well, but how would you handle both a 4 byte uint32_t and a 32byte char array (string)?

Comment: You note that you want to "store them in a common array".  Why do you want this to be the solution?  Can you design a getter that abstracts the actual storage from the rest of your code?  That way you won't have to go down the union route...  We can tell you ways to solve the given problem (basically unions), but if you describe the wider problem better you're apt to get better solutions.

Comment: Define "efficient".

Comment: Define "correct"

Comment: efficient -> doesn't waste more space than required if possible; correct -> industry-acknowledged

Comment: Creating a "variant" through union is widely recognized as bad practice, which in turns originates from bad program design. There should never be a need to create such types, since that's not how you do generic programming in C.

Comment: @Lundin: Feel free to provide an alternative solution. Consider a machine with multiple types of sensors in a memory-limited environment (microcontroller). malloc is forbidden by design.

Comment: @TomL. On such systems in particular, variants are forbidden, most because they don't make much sense. See for example MISRA-C. But the root of the problem here is that your system is 100% deterministic, yet you suggest a program design which assumes that the system isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Efficient storage of parameters in C

Let us assume a fixed size per parameter.

> So basically the largest parameter was a 32byte string

So we need at least 32 bytes.  Use a `union` to overlay the various types of data.

```
typedef union {
  char s[32];
  TBD;
} valueType;
```

A *string* always ends with a *null character* so code can use the last `char` `string[32-1]` zero-ness as a flag for `string` vs. non-string.

For other types, keep track via a `.type_identifier` member.

```
typedef union {
  char string[32];
  struct {
    union {
      struct { uint32_t val; uint32_t min; uint32_t max; uint32_t  initial; } t_uint32;
      struct { float val;    float min;    float max;    float initial; } t_float;
      struct { char val;     char min;     char max;     char initial; } t_char;
    } u; 
    uint8_t type_identifier;
    uint8_t access_mode;
  } not_string; 
} valueType;
```

This is fine when the size of `.not_string` is less than the size of `.string`.

---

Yet OP wants to code `double`, which commonly takes 8 bytes each and also wants 4 `double`members.

So might as well:

```
typedef struct {
  int type_identifier;  // or  uint8_t
  int access_mode;      // or  uint8_t
  union {
    char string[32];
    struct { uint32_t val; uint32_t min; uint32_t max; uint32_t  initial; } t_uint32;
    struct { double val;   double min;   double max;   double initial; } t_double;
    struct { float val;    float min;    float max;    float initial; } t_float;
    struct { char val;     char min;     char max;     char initial; } t_char;
  } u; 
} valueType;
```

This may be as small as 2 + 32 bytes or a tad larger depending on padding requirements.

Comment: Having a custom parameter type (t_uint32) is a great idea. Seems very useful to me.

Answer (score 2):

Unions are the way to go! Have an `enum` saying what type is stored there (I've used an `int_8` to make the example small) and then do this:

```
struct {
    int_8 type;
    union {
        int_8 eight_wide_thing;
        char char_buffer[42];
        double more_bad_variable_names;
    }
    int_32 foo_count;
} example;
```

You can do this:

```
struct example bar;
bar.eight_wide_thing = 42;
printf("%d", bar.eight_wide_thing);
bar.char_buffer[3] = '\0';
bar.char_buffer[0] = 'H';
bar.char_buffer[1] = 'i';
bar.char_buffer[2] = '!';
printf("%s", bar.char_buffer);
```

But not this:

```
bar.eight_wide_thing = 42;
bar.more_bad_variable_names /= 6;
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this would allocate memory of 58 bytes for each instance (assuming double is 8 bytes), even if I just want to store a single uint8_t. Correct?

Comment: @TomL. Yes. If you use pointers instead, it will only allocate `sizeof(void *); but you'll need to deal with memory allocation and deallocation manually.

Comment: @TomL. Wait; the union part will only be 42 bytes.

Comment: I'm trying to just use static memory allocation as this is intended for an embedded system where I don't want to deal with malloc.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, unions just reserve space for the largest element if I remember correctly.

Comment: Which makes 47 bytes, assuming `char` is 1 which I think is a given.

Comment: What would be foo_count and why can't I do the second two things of your example? Or do you just mean that I can't do those in sequence?

Comment: `foo_count` is the number of `foo`s. It's irrelevant. And it's in sequence that you can't do them, yes.

Comment: The actual size of the union will depend on how your compiler aligns/pads the structure, and this is usually very dependent on the memory access methods of the target processor, i.e. only if your compiler generates byte address will the size of the union be 47 - best method is to write some simple code which prints the sizeof the union. Your desired method can work but can create a lot of overhead (wasted RAM) if most instances of this union hold eight-wide-thing values.

Comment: @barny You are correct; I forgot about that. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @barny: The correct way would be to read the ABI of the implementation for the specific platform and **then** verify the length (I've seen broken implementations which don't follow the ABI in all aspects). Also it's not guaranteed there is no "filler" bytes between different data objects which don't belong to any object. Said that: it's a bad idea to rely on a specific layout for a `struct`. Luckily it's most times also completely irrelevant, if the code is written correctly these days even on common MCUs.

Comment: my way of saying it is never use structs (unions/bitfields) across compile domains.  If you properly use a struct (union, etc) within a program and only access the union/struct items directly you never point a struct at memory or fread into or out of a struct, never memcpy into or out of except into another one declared and compiled into that code and use sizeof(), you will be fine, even with bitfields.  its when you make any kind of assumption as to the size you get into trouble eventually.  usually when it is most painful to the project.

Comment: the job of the union is just to save on consumption for items that are mutually exclusive which is why a union sounds so tempting to your question.  if the data type can be one of your list, only one at a time of your list, then you can save some space in the struct by using a union, and the largest of those items (plus target and compiler padding) will define the width of that union, where each of the union items lands within that width is target and compiler specific, not just brand of compiler specific but version, build options, etc.

Comment: If you dont need to save the space then there is no need for the union just have one of each of the types in the struct and just use the appropriate one based on the type.

Comment: I think I understand where this is heading. Space is at least a little of concern even if it's not the most pressing issue.

Comment: My point wasn't about so much how to establish the size (but clearly running code on the target to tell you what the size of the structure is *will* tell you the space it takes) as that a simple adding up of the bytes involved may well not be the actual size of the union - and if the OP wants "efficient" storage then the "efficiency" of struct-containing-a-union-of-all-the-possible-types depends on their usage because wasted space could be very large if perhaps 99.99% of values stored in this struct are in fact only 1 byte of actual data.